# Write array of dictionaries to csv in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv

I have been wrestling with this for a day or two now, and I can't seem to get it right.

```
project_index = [
{A: ['1', '2', '3']},
{B: ['4', '5', '6']},
{C: ['7', '8', '9']},
{D: ['10', '11', '12']},
{E: ['13', '14', '15']},
{F: ['16', '17', '18']}
]
```

I have tried so many different things to try to get this into a .CSV table, but it keeps coming out in ridiculously incorrect format, eg them tiling down diagonally, or a bunch of rows of just the keys over and over (EG:

A B C D E F

A B C D E F

A B C D E F

A B C D E F )

Also, even if I get the values to show up, the entire array of strings shows up in one cell.

Is there any way I can get it to make each dictionary a column, with each string in the array value as its own cell in said column?

Example:
[image: Example Table]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you show us what you have attempted, and what your desired output should be?

Comment: I don't have all the snippets of code that I've tried, but I have edited the post with a screenshot of what the result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your keys are unique... then this (Modified Slightly):

```
project_index = [
{'A': ['1', '2', '3']},
{'B': ['4', '5', '6']},
{'C': ['7', '8', '9']},
{'D': ['10', '11', '12', '20']},
{'E': ['13', '14', '15']},
{'F': ['16', '17', '18']}
]
```

Should probably look like this:

```
project_index_dict = {}
for x in project_index:
    project_index_dict.update(x)

print(project_index_dict)
# Output:
 
{'A': ['1', '2', '3'],
 'B': ['4', '5', '6'],
 'C': ['7', '8', '9'],
 'D': ['10', '11', '12', '20'],
 'E': ['13', '14', '15'],
 'F': ['16', '17', '18']}
```

At this point, rather than re-invent the wheel... you could just use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Work-around for uneven lengths:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(project_index_dict, 'index').T.fillna('')
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Output `file.csv`:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,4,7,10,13,16
2,5,8,11,14,17
3,6,9,12,15,18
,,,20,,
```

---

---

`csv` module method:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

header = []
for d in project_index:
    header.extend(list(d))

project_index_rows = [dict(zip(header, x)) for x in 
                      zip_longest(*chain(list(*p.values()) 
                                         for p in project_index), 
                                  fillvalue='')]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(project_index_rows)
```

Comment: I have a feeling this might be homework, so OP *might* not be able/allowed to use pandas -- Just an observation.

Comment: Ahhh, it's so close!  I tested it on the example, and that worked - however, the actual data I'm trying to do this with, is not all the same length, and as such I got the error:

```ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length```

Comment: This solution got my vote. @Lif, please post a portion of your data which causes trouble and what kind of output you want to see. Thank you.

Comment: Brilliance - thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My solution does not use Pandas. Here is the plan:

- For the header row, grab all the keys from the dictionaries
- For the data row, use `zip` to transpose columns -> rows

```py
import csv

def first_key(d):
    """Return the first key in a dictionary."""
    return next(iter(d))

def first_value(d):
    """Return the first value in a dictionary."""
    return next(iter(d.values()))
    
with open("output.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(first_key(d) for d in project_index)

    # Write the rest
    rows = zip(*[first_value(d) for d in project_index])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Contents of output.csv:

```
A,B,C,D,D,F
1,4,7,10,13,16
2,5,8,11,14,17
3,6,9,12,15,18
```

Comment: If you simply swap out `zip` for `itertools`'s `zip_longest`, this works for uneven-length lists as well~

Comment: Good idea. Unless the rows are missing cells in the middle.